# How to pass new lines in txt file in Python code to apply function to different strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have a Python code that translates amino acid sequences into DNA sequences:

```
# Read the file and get the Peptide string
file = open('../Results/sample_dna2.txt', 'r')
dna = file.read()
#print(dna)

# Protein codon table
protein = {
  'A': ('GCC'),
  'B': ('GAC'),
  'C': ('TGC'),
  'D': ('GAC'),
  'E': ('GAG'),
  'F': ('TTC'),
  'G': ('GGC'),
  'H': ('CAC'),
  'I': ('ATC'),
  'K': ('AAG'),
  'L': ('CTG'),
  'M': ('ATG'),
  'N': ('AAC'),
  'P': ('CCC'),
  'Q': ('CAG'),
  'R': ('AGG'),
  'S': ('AGC'),
  'T': ('ACC'),
  'V': ('GTG'),
  'W': ('TGG',),
  'Y': ('TAC'),
  '*': ('TGA'),
}

dna_sequence = ""

# Generate DNA sequence
for i in range(0, len(dna)-(0+len(dna)%1), 1):
    dna_sequence += protein[dna[i:i+1]]

# Print the DNA sequence
print (dna_sequence)
```

The code works when the text file is in this format:

```
ABBBC
```

But the code does not work when the text file is like this:

```
ABBBC

ABBBC
```

I get the following error from Python:

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-35-8a6fd8cd8220>     in <module>

35 # Generate DNA sequence 
36 for i in range(0, len(dna)-(0+len(dna)%1), 1): --->
37 dna_sequence += protein[dna[i:i+1]] 
38 
39 # Print the DNA sequence KeyError: '\n'
```

How can I fix the code so that it passes the new line and translate the next peptide sequence? Please note I am very new to Python so any help will be greatly appreciated.

I would like the result to be like this please:

```
CTGATC

CTGATC
```

Comment: Please provide the text samples as text, not as images.

Comment: The line after `for` should be indented if it should run in the `for` loop. If not, you need to explain in more detail what you hope for this code to do.

Comment: Hi tripleee,  I have now changed the image to texts. Is it more clear now?. I have now indented the line.

Comment: The traceback doesn't contain the actual error message, could you please add that in? But I guess you are getting a `KeyError` because newline (`\n`) is not a key in your dict.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```py
# Generate DNA sequence

for i in range(0, len(dna)-(0+len(dna)%1), 1):
    try:
        dna_sequence += protein[dna[i:i+1]]
    except KeyError:
        dna_sequence += dna[i:i+1]
```

Comment: The blanket `except` is a ticking time bomb; you really should only trap the expception yow expect (as speculated earlier, `KeyError`).

Answer (score 0):

Read in your file line by line rather than all at the same time, for example,

```
file = open('../Results/sample_dna2.txt', 'r')
file_lines = file.readlines()
dna = []
for f in file_lines:
    dna.append(f)
```

Now you have a list `dna` that you can iterate over..

```
dna_sequence = ""
# Generate DNA sequence
for sequence in dna:
    for i in range(0, len(sequence)-(0+len(sequence)%1), 1):
        dna_sequence += protein[sequence[i:i+1]]

print (dna_sequnce)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `range` in your script is very odd. The value of `0+len(sequence)%1` will simply be equal to `len(sequence)` for every possible value; and anyway, you simply seem to mean `range(len(sequence))`.

Here's an alternative solution which doesn't use exceptions, and instead gets rid of any trailing whitespace, including newlines.  Blindly ignoring any `KeyError` would simply discard any unknown sequences in the input, not just newlines -- you definitely want to get a warning if your input doesn't match your expectations.

It also processes a single line at a time, so that you don't have to read the entire input into memory. For small inputs, it probably doesn't matter, but for large inputs, you definitely want to avoid keeping everything in memory.

```py
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input:
    for line in input:
        dna = line.rstrip()
        sequence = []
        for i in range(len(dna)):
            sequence.append(protein[dna[i:i+1]])
        print(''.join(sequence))
```

This also allows you to pass in the input file name as a command-line parameter -- you get it in `sys.argv[1]` which of course requires `import sys` near the beginning of the script.